# IE not working with jQuery .show()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, show

I built some simple tabs, which when clicked, show a hidden div.  Very simple.  All works well, except in IE.  For some reason, even though I am using the jQuery .show() function, it won't set the hidden div to display:block, but just leaves it hidden, and it is very frustrating.

Example Page: http://www.puc.edu/alumni/give-puc

jQuery for tabs:

```
$('#teamTabs li').click(function() {
 $('#teamTabs li').removeClass('selected');
 $(this).addClass('selected');
 $('.teamTab').hide();
 var id = $(this).attr('id');
 if (id == 'teamTab1') {
  $('#team1').show();
 } else if (id == 'teamTab2') {
  $('#team2').show();
 } else if (id == 'teamTab3') {
  $('#team3').show();
 } else if (id == 'teamTab4') {
  $('#team4').show();
 }//end else if

 return false;

});//end click
```

Any ideas why IE wouldn't set the div to display:block?

Comment: What version of IE? Which versions do you need to support?

Comment: Seems to work OK for me in IE8

Comment: IE7 is what is not working for me.

Comment: Try alert(id);  what is shown?

Comment: Hmmm, I am testing it again now and it is working.  Did I accidently solve my problem?  Looks like it...

Comment: Checked your styles through FireBug, is it possible your teamtab class had display: none listed as !important?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize you've already figured out the problem was elsewhere, but for others finding this later (and to get this off the no answers list), you can slim down/simplify your code quite a bit:

```
$('#teamTabs li').click(function() {
  $(this).addClass('selected').siblings().removeClass('selected');
  $('.teamTab').hide();
  $('#team'+ this.id.replace('teamTab','')).show();
  return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I found that IE actually was changing display to block, but it also made each `display:none;` block have `visibility:hidden;`

I was able to get my elements to show correctly by doing the following:

```
$('#team1').show(); // shows for all browsers but IE
if($.browser.msie){
   $('#team1').css({"visibility":"visible"});
}
```

I found this by using two alerts after narrowing down my issue to the two possible CSS elements that could hide my HTML: display:none; and visibility:hidden.

Guaranteed that if you do this alert right after `$('#team1').show();`

`alert( $('#team1').css("display"));` your display will be block and
alert( $('#team1').css("visibility")); your visibility will be hidden.

Seems like IE automatically hides blocks when they are set to a display of "none" in the css and then changed via Jquery. It also seems as though this isn't an issue for elements that are defined as display:block; These elements should always be ok as long as you defined them first in the CSS.

Hope this helps anyone else out there having this issue :)